# Proving various runtimes have various big-O complexities?

Tags: math, big-o

How can I prove the following:

1. 10 n log n ∈ O(2n<sup>2</sup>)
2. n log n + 40 · 2<sup>n</sup> - 6n ∈ O(2<sup>n</sup>)

In the first one, I'm using this math:

> 10 n log n ≤ c · 2n<sup>2</sup>
>
> 10 n<sup>2</sup> ≤ c · 2n<sup>2</sup>  divide by 2
>
> 5 n<sup>2</sup> ≤ c · n<sup>2</sup>

I'm guessing that c = 5 and n<sub>0</sub> = 1, but I'm not sure if that's true.

In the second one, I tried to multiply the left hand side by 2<sup>n</sup> but that didn't end up working. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks .. what I need is hint or steps because they are really confusing

Comment: The constant multipliers don't matter; what's crucial for the first one is that O(n log n) is a lower order than O(n^2), so the bound for O(n log n) is smaller than the bound for O(n^2).  Similarly, in the second, the biggest term on the LHS is O(2^n), so the O(n log n) and O(n) terms are immaterial and the proof follows.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Your proof is basically correct, but if the instructor wants to see why the n log n can be bounded by n^2 or 2^n, you would have to do a little bit more. However, I believe that the answer to this question should be in any number of CS books.

Comment: @NUMONE for the second question, show that if f(n) is O(g(n)) then f(n) + g(n) is O(g(n)).  Then, show that n log n is O(2^n) and 6n is O(2^n).

Comment: This looks more like a mathoverflow or math.stackexchange.com question

Comment: Listen to Jonathan Leffler (and arne). Focus on (n log(n)) in the first one and on (n log(n + 2^n - n) in the second one. Remember that we have (growing order): exponential function > power function > linear function > logarithmic function > constant

Answer (score 0):

For part (1), you want to prove

> 10 n log n = O(2n<sup>2</sup>)

It might help to note that for any n ≥ 1 that

> log n < n

Therefore, you have that

> 10 n log n ≤ 10 n<sup>2</sup> = 5(2n<sup>2</sup>)

Therefore, you can conclude that 10n log n = O(2n<sup>2</sup>) because you can choose n<sub>0</sub> = 1 and c = 5 and use the formal definition of big-O.

For part (i), you want to prove

> n log n + 40 · 2<sup>n</sup> - 6n = O(2<sup>n</sup>)

One useful fact you might want to use here is that n<sup>2</sup> ≤ 2<sup>n</sup> for any n ≥ 4. Therefore, we get that, whenever n ≥ 4

> n log n + 40 · 2<sup>n</sup> - 6n ≤ n log n + 40 · 2<sup>n</sup> ≤ 40 · 2<sup>n</sup> + n<sup>2</sup> ≤ 40 · 2<sup>n</sup> + 2<sup>n</sup> = 41 · 2<sup>n</sup>

Therefore, if you pick n<sub>0</sub> = 4 and c = 41, you can use the formal definition of big-O to prove that n log n + 40 · 2<sup>n</sup> - 6n = O(2<sup>n</sup>).

Hope this helps!